# Where does Tomcat invoke Java?

Tags: java, tomcat

It's not possible to start any Java program other than to use the java launcher.

But when I start Tomcat or any other app server, I don't literally run a java program. I choose `start server`.

When a server is started (Tomcat for this case), where is the actual place that the java is invoked?

Comment: The shell script will start java.

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect. Any suitable JNI wrapper can start a Java program, via the Invocation API. The Java launcher is one example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in your tomcat installation you will find a file called catalina.bat or catalina.sh. In this file you will find all the commands that start Tomcat. You will see that it actually calls the jvm and passes some parameters. The startup.bat or startup.sh file is just a script that makes it easy for you to run the application.

See the [source here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/bin/catalina.bat).

The line that starts:

```
   %_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS%
```

close to the end is the line that actually runs the Java command. The %VARIABLE%  syntax are variables that are all set previously. Trace back through the file to see what each one is set to and you can reconstruct the command that is being executed.

Comment: think this is the one that makes better sense... hold on checking the link

Comment: hmm but I don't see the java command? i mean i just think somewhere java.exe is called..

Comment: aha! so you mean "EXECJAVA" becomes "java" and passed with params

Comment: That's right. It can be a bit confusing due to the number of options that they make possible.

Answer (score 2):

Servers are normal programs. There is no java launcher. When you start tomcat, you start java and point it to the tomcat JARs, thus starting tomcat.

Comment: hmm... but how can java programs run without a jvm?

Comment: Tomcat is a runtime environment for Servlet and Jsp's. If there is no JVM the Tomcat installation as well as startup will fail.

Comment: Hmm @StefanBeike, so it appears that Tomcat is a jvm by itself?

Comment: @KishoreE no it runs on JVM but its not JVM itself

Answer (score 1):

> now when I start Tomcat or any other app server, I don't literally run
>   a java program. I choose "start server".

False.  Tomcat **is** a Java program.  When you start Tomcat via the startup scripts (catalina.sh/bat and/or startup.sh/bat) you will see that the script does various checks to find where Java is installed and ultimately runs something to the effect of

```
CLASSPATH="something;yadda-yadda.jar" java org.apache.catalina.Bootstrap
```

When you start it as a Windows service, the above scripting is less obvious and is buried in a combination of registry keys and an executable file, but the overall process is the same, it finds where Java is installed and executes it, specifying the Tomcat entry point class which has the `public static void main` method.

The default mode to run it as a service on Windows is "jvm", which actually loads tomcat7.exe (I think that is the right file name) which loads in `jvm.dll` to embed Java in the process.  You can change the service to "java" mode, which works like the shell scripts, executing "java.exe" as a process.

Comment: this sir i know, where im confused is to find how tomcat creates the jre before starting up

Comment: catalina.sh on *nix systems, catalina.bat on Windows systems.  If running as a Windows service, it's somewhere in the tomcat7.exe file that it figures it out.  I've amended my answer to include the service details.

Comment: i give you point for answering, but it's quite vague still. thanks though1

Comment: I have told you the exact files which start Java and how it does it.  What did I not answer clearly?  How can I improve my answer?